# How to burn .hex intel format file on cc2530 EB

Tags: hex, evaluation, sdcc, contiki

Hello there I am a newbie working on the SMARTRF-05EB - Evaluation Board, I have installed SDCC and Contiki-2.6 in the  Linux Virtual Machine. I am able to build all the examples present in this directory contiki-2.6/contiki/examples/cc2530dk , but I am clueless as to how to flash the final .hex image file on EB.

Is there a way to burn it from Linux directly using some command or do I have to switch back to Windows and use TI's Flash Programmer to burn the application image. When I try to flash the application using the Flash Programmer I get this message highlighted in RED : "Flash Image overlaps with the bootloader"

Can someone please let me know about how to correctly place the application code on a particular address so that I can save the bootloader from being corrupted by my application .hex file.

I would like to flash say for example the simple "hello world"  .hex file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello there I had to figure it out by going through the documentation..so the commmand that I used in getting a successful output on the hardware was this

```
1) root@ubuntu:/home/contiki/contiki-2.6/examples/cc2530dk# make TARGET=cc2530dk clean
2) root@ubuntu:/home/contiki/contiki-2.6/examples/cc2530dk# make TARGET=cc2530dk
```

also in the previous directory, cd to hello-world and execute the 2 commands as below:

```
1) root@ubuntu:/home/contiki/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world# make TARGET=cc2530dk clean
2) root@ubuntu:/home/contiki/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world# make TARGET=cc2530dk
```

These 2 commands help in building the .hex for the SMART05-EB and then use the TI's SMARTRF STUDIO software or TI's Flash Programmer for burning the hex image on the SoC. Open up TeraTerm or anyother Serial Communication software and then choose the port with settings 115200 8-N-1 and you should be able to get the output on screen. I have issues in building the other examples in other directory - for eg ping-ipv6, so would be posting a new question regarding such examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After compiling the code for the example you are working with it 'll create a platform specific file Ex. for sky (hello-world.sky) in you case it 'll be hello-world.cc2538dk. Just use the following command to convert it to ihex file

`msp430-objcopy udp-multicast.exp2420 -O ihex udp-multicast.ihex`

You can now rename the ihex file to hex file and upload the hex file to your mote using TI flash program (http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_Flasher_-_Command_Line_Programmer). From windows use the following command to upload the file.

`MSP430Flasher.exe -n "MSP430F5438A" -m SBW4 -w your_hex_file.hex -i COMxx [VCC]`

Comment: hello @Sarwarul sincere thanks for the solution. But I would like to do it from Linux & IAR workbench IDE, is it possible? if so please let me know. Also I would like clarify about the device list here would the 3rd argument be "MSP2530" in my case for SmartRF-05 Evaluation Board. I tried with "MSP2530" after downloading the datasheet for MSP2530. But I got a big message and out of that this is what I would like to post " Checking for available FET debuggers:
 Couldn't find any connected USB FETs!". So certainly I am going wrong with the commands - thanks for your help

Comment: Hello @Sawarul Choudhary I would like to clarify that the 3 option in the command to upload the hex file on to the device should be not related to MSP? I would like to program the collector device which has the main chip as CC2530, so would the command change accordingly. Had it been that I was suppose to program the MSP device I would have used the MSP device as the 3rd argument. So please let me know where to find the command parameters and the corresponding 3rd parameter of cc2530 to upload the hex file. I could manage to burn the hex file using TI's flasher,but still clueless about output

Comment: @user239205 IAR does not support Linux environment